# проблемы с кодом

Tags: c++

по задумке я хотел чтобы было 4 файла
world . cpp  ( файл в котором код )
world . txt  ( файл где написана версия ( пример 0 ) )
real_world . cpp ( файл с обновленым кодом )
real_world . txt ( файл с версией ( пример 1 ) )

я хотел так чтобы файл world .txt и real_world . txt считывались
в них хранится версия программы. 
если текст файлов не тот же что и в другом тогда программа брала код из real_world . cpp и загружала его в world . cpp

```
// update.cpp : Этот файл содержит функцию "main". 

#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

string fille;   // название файла
string version; // текушая версия файла

string updates; // файл с обновлением
string upVersion; // версия файла с обновлением

void filles()
{
    cout << "Введите название файла/программы" << endl;
    cin >> fille;

    cout << "Введите версию файла/программы" << endl;
    cin >> version;

    cout << "Введите файл с обновлением файла/программы" << endl;
    cin >> updates;

    cout << "Введите версию файла/программы с обновлением" << endl;
    cin >> upVersion;
}

void update()
{
    char update[50];
    ifstream ifs(version);  // version
    ifs >> update;

    ifs.getline(update, 50);
    ifs.close();
    cout << "текушая версия файла: " << update << endl;
    string def_version = update;

    update[50];
    ifstream ifst(upVersion); // upVersion
    ifst >> update;

    ifst.getline(update, 50);
    ifst.close();
    cout << "версия файла с обновлением: " << update << endl;
    string up_version = update;

    if (def_version != up_version)
    {
        ifstream ifs(updates); // update
        ifs >> update;

        ifs.getline(update, 50);
        ifs.close();
        cout << "Код: " << update << endl;

        ofstream ofs(fille);
        ofs.open(fille);
        ofs << update << endl;
        ofs.close();
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    filles();
    if(version != upVersion) update();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А вопрос в чем?

Comment: В вопросе явно не хватает продолжения с описанием сути проблемы

Comment: получается не то что нужно, он толи не может считать текст и код или я рукажопый Введите название файла/программы
world.cpp
Введите версию файла/программы
world.txt
Введите файл с обновлением файла/программы
real_world.cpp
Введите версию файла/программы с обновлением
real_world.txt
текушая версия файла:
версия файла с обновлением:
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .